# Symfony functional test fail but the same request works in browser

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

I followed the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#functional-tests) about functional tests in order to write my first one, but I have some issues. The response I get via browser works good:

[image: Browser response]

But when I run `phpunit -c app/` in the shell I get a failure.

> 1)
>   AppBundle\Tests\Controller\MeterAPIControllerTest::testGetAllVariables
>       Failed asserting that 500 matches expected 200.

This is the code:

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class MeterAPIControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testGetAllVariables()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request(
            'GET',
            '/meters/121/120/variables'
        );

        // Assert a specific 200 status code
        $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode()); 
    }
}
```

If I try another test assertion, I get failure too.

```php
// Assert that the "Content-Type" header is "application/json"
$this->assertTrue(
    $client->getResponse()->headers->contains(
        'Content-Type',
        'application/json'
    )
);
```

**EDIT**

When I run `phpunit` in `app/logs/test.log` I get a PHP Exception:

> [2016-03-31 15:25:21] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: "Invalid mapping
>   file 'AppBundle.Entity.EM2Meter.orm.yml' for class
>   'AppBundle\Entity\EM2Meter'." at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iso50k1_tst_symfony/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php
>   line 86 {"exception":"[object]
>   (Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException(code: 0):
>   Invalid mapping file 'AppBundle.Entity.EM2Meter.orm.yml' for class
>   'AppBundle\Entity\EM2Meter'. at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iso50k1_tst_symfony/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php:86)"}
>   []

How can I fix this?

Comment: are you sure your requesting to the correct port?

Comment: @DevDonkey Yes, the request is correct.

Comment: are you sure? I think you'll find that unless you specify when you instantiate a new client, itll default to port 80.

Comment: Do you solve it please ?

Answer (score 3):

You have not told the symfony client to contact the localhost server on port 8000, its still defaulting to 80.

When you instantiate your client, specify the host like this.

```
$client = static::createClient([], [
    'HTTP_HOST' => 'localhost:8000',
] );
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a cache problem here. I think it is a good practice to clean cache for the current environment before running the tests and before running your project for functional tests:

`$ php bin/console cache:clear --env=dev`

`$ php bin/console cache:clear --env=tests`