# PHPUnit test in Symfony 5 - unit test always return a 404 or 500

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, symfony5

### Configuration :

**OS** : MacOS Catalina 10.15.4 
**Web server** : Apache (using MAMP) 
**PHP version** : 7.3.9 
**Symfony version** : Symfony CLI version v4.16.3 
**Composer version** : Composer version 1.10.7

## Issue :

I started using PHPUnit as mentioned in the Symfony documentation about testing, and I wanted to try it with a simple test: send get request to my main page (route = '/') and see if I have a 200 status code as expected.

## My process :

In my project :

```sh
composer req --dev Symfony/PHPUnit-bridge Symfony/css-selector symfony/browser-kit symfony/maker-bundle
```

```sh
bin/console make:functional-test MainControllerTest
```

and here is the test file in tests/ :

```php
<?php


namespace App\Tests\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;


class MainControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{


    public function testIndex()
    {
        $c = static::createClient();
        $c->request('GET','/');
        $this->assertEquals(200, $c->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), 'REQUEST IS : ' . $c->getRequest());
    }
}
```

So this is the basic test controller, I just modified it a bit by customizing the output message to get my request as an output.

then :

```sh
bin/PHPUnit tests
```

and finally my output :

```sh
PHPUnit 8.3.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.3.8 with Xdebug 2.7.2
Configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DEV/symfony_app/phpunit.xml

Testing tests
F                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 947 ms, Memory: 24.00 MB

There was 1 failure:

1) App\Tests\Controller\MainControllerTest::testIndex

REQUEST IS : GET /DEV/symfony_app/public/index.php/dossier/all HTTP/1.1
Accept:          text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Host:            localhost:8888
User-Agent:      Symfony BrowserKit
X-Php-Ob-Level:  1


Failed asserting that 404 matches expected 200.

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/DEV/symfony_app/tests/Controller/MainControllerTest.php:16

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

But my web server is running and I can access my '/' route, I've tried changing the Uri to 'http://localhost:8888/DEV/symfony_app/public/' or 'http://localhost:8888/DEV/symfony_app/public/index.php'

but it always returns 404 instead of 200.

I've configured some routes and main is one of them if you are not authenticated you are redirected to '/login' which is one of the only routes you can access as an anonymous user, so I tried to this test with my '/login' route but I also have 404 status.

I'm literally at the beginning of the [testing documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html) but if this simple test doesn't work I can't go further.

Any clue on this?

### Similar issues I saw :

[Symfony functional test fail but the same request works in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36326998/symfony-functional-test-fail-but-the-same-request-works-in-browser)

*Unfortunately, none of the answers fixed my problem*

Comment: Any errors in `test` logs?

Comment: Do you have any firewalls ? Can we see them ? Also, make sure you're accessing to the right database, test can disable database (see `config/package/test/doctrine.yaml` if it exists).

Comment: @Leprechaun I don't even have a log at all

Comment: @Benjamin I've configured my database URL in phpunit.xml.dist in my tests/ folder and same thing in my phpunit.xml file, they're both using the same URL as the project in dev environment (which is working), I don't have the config/package/test/doctrine.yaml file, this file is located in the package dir not in the test dir

Comment: @LightninWolf can you confirm that `$c` is an instance of `KernelBrowser`? I also notice this line in your output `REQUEST IS : GET /DEV/symfony_app/public/index.php/dossier/all` - is it correct? Did you try accessing private routes by [loggin in a user](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#logging-in-users-authentication)?

Comment: @MartinM. $c is defined in the 1st line of the testIndex function, as I said I'm new with phpunit testing so I don't know what is this KernelBrowser class. concerning the route, as I said, yes dossier/all is protected, you have to be logged, but I have the same issue with /login which is not a protected route.

Comment: @LightninWolf I have the same problem, in Symfony 5.1 - unit test always return  500 on method GET.
How did you resolve issue?

Comment: the issue is still not solved, I'm still working on this project and sometimes I retry but it's been weeks and I do not have any solutions

Comment: Hello @LightninWolf do you solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it reminded me of getting an error on production, it always returned 404 not found, but really the error was 500 error.

so on `.env.test.local` I changed `APP_DEBUG=true`, and then from the `$client->getResponse`, I found out that it was actually giving 500 error because the test database was empty

check if you are actually getting 404 or is it actual 500.